# Could not connect to Kafka headless service

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka

recently I have encountered a problem with Kafka (running on our company's K8S system). Every thing was running fine then suddenly all of my kafka and zookeeper pods could not connect to their headless services (the pods are still in running state), which results in timeout exception everytime I pushlish a message into a topic. Below is an image from the log of a zookeeper pod:

[image]

The same things happen to all of my broker pods.
Have anyone faced with this problem and solved it? Please let me know.
Thanks in advance! By the way I'm sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

this seems like networking problem, "no route to host"